# How can I pass 2 parameters to my middle-ware on my admin controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware, controllers

I have an admin-controller and i want to passe to it middle-ware to parameters to allow **Super Admin** to do admin stuff.

Here my controller:

```
class adminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('admin');
    }
    public function showGenerateCode(){
        $code ="";
        return view('create_code',compact('code'));
    }
    public function generateCode(Request $request){
        $phone = $request['phone'];
        $code = "";
        $user = User::where('phone' ,'=',$phone)->first();
        if($user){
            $code = "Ce numero de telephone et deja associé a un utilisateur";
            return view('create_code',compact('code'));
            //dd($code);
        }
        else{
            $code = "Code d'autorisation générer avec succé : ".substr($phone,1,3).rand(1000000,9999999);
            return view('create_code',compact('code'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass them as an array

```
$this->middleware(['admin', 'superAdmin']);
```

If it does not work with an array, pass each of them separately

```
$this->middleware('admin');
$this->middleware('superAdmin');
```

Not a solution to your issue, but a workaround since everything you try is not working. You could remove the middleware from the constructor and instead apply them to the routes that call the functions from that constructor

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin', 'superadmin']], function(){
    Route::get('url1', 'adminController@function1');
    Route::get('url2', 'adminController@function2');
    Route::post('url3', 'adminController@function3');
});
```

Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: i tried that , but it didn't work ! and when i try by just 1 parameter it works ! either admin or super admin

Comment: same still doesn't work ! 
when i'm trying with middleware('admin') or middleware superadmin alone its working !

Comment: Glad. Don't forget to mark my answer please. Thanks :)